# Should I use repeated measures ANOVA or one-way ANOVA?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, image-processing

I am conducting a study on different image reconstruction algorithms for computed tomography (CT). My aim is to investigate which of the image reconstruction algorithms that have the highest signal-to-noise ratio (SNR). My dataset is 100 patients who underwent a CT brain scan. Each CT scan will be reconstructed with 4 different image reconstruction algorithms. Then I will measure the SNR for each algorithm and patient and compare the different reconstruction algorithms with regard to the SNR. So, we scan the patient's head and then the computer at once provides four different image reconstruction algorithms of the scan (4 different image sets) and then we measure the SNR of each image set and compare it to the other reconstruction algorithms (other image sets). Or, if it makes it easier for you to think. Consider the following corresponding scenario: You take a blood sample (corresponding to "CT scan") from the patient and measure the glucose level with 4 different apparatus (corresponding to the 4 different image reconstruction algorithms). And then you compare the blood glucose level (corresponding to "the SNR") between the four different apparatus. So, my question is if I should use a repeated measures ANOVA or just an ordinary one-way ANOVA.

Comment: It will be easier for people to understand the question/problem if you could describe the dataset. Also, what is your research question ?

Comment: Hello Robert, thank you for your reply. The dataset is the following: 100 patients who underwent a CT brain scan. The CT brain scans will be reconstructed with 4 different image reconstruction algorithms. I will measure the signal-to-noise (SNR) ratio of a ROI placed on a certain brain level at a certain area of the brain. The SNRs will be compared between the different image reconstructions. Should I perform a repeated measures ANOVA since it is the same patients reconstructed with 4 different image reconstruction algorithms? Or should i choose an ordinary one-way ANOVA? Thank you!

Comment: I have updated my question and provided more information about my study as well as a corresponding scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have repeated measures within subjects it is necessary to control for the non-independence of observations within subjects. That is, observations within one subject are likely to be more similar than observations in other subjects.

So in this case you will need to use a repeated measures ANOVA

Comment: Thank you so much Robert!

Comment: @Michael does this answer your question ? If so then please consider upvoting, and marking it as the accepted answer. If not please let us know why ?

Comment: Hello Robert! Thank you again for your reply. Do you mean "observations within one subject are likely to be more similar THAN observations in other subjects", not "observations within one subject are likely to be more similar TO observations in other subjects". Apart from that I totally agree with you.

Comment: @Michael YES ! thank you for spotting that typo - I've edited my answer accordingly :)

Comment: Thank you Robert! I did some more thinking. I actually don't think that I have repeated measures in this study. I am not actually taking measurement over time to look for changes. Instead, I am using 4 different algorithms on the same CT-scan (and only 1 scan per subject), to see which which is best by calculating the SNR for each algorithm. I don't even think that I have any replication. Perhaps I did not clarify the project enough for you, please see below:

Comment: So, I am conducting a study on different image reconstruction algorithms for computed tomography (CT). My aim is to investigate which of the image reconstruction algorithms that have the highest signal-to-noise ratio (SNR). My dataset is 100 patients who underwent a CT brain scan. Each CT scan will be reconstructed with 4 different image reconstruction algorithms. Then I will measure the SNR for each algorithm and patient and compare the different reconstruction algorithms with regard to the SNR.

Comment: Do you still think that I need to use repeated measures ANOVA? Please let me know if you need any more information! /All the best Michael

Comment: Ahhh. This is very interesting. You say *"I am using 4 different algorithms on the same CT-scan (and only 1 scan per subject)"* so I interpret this as repeated measures on the scans.  Is that right ?

Comment: Very interesting indeed, and the literature varies on the subject as well when it comes to the statistical analyses. What we are doing is that we scan the patient's head and then the computer at once provides four different image reconstruction algorithms of the scan (4 different image sets) and then we measure the SNR of each image set and compare it to the other reconstruction algorithms (other image sets). This study for instance: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6424830/ ;is applying 3 different image reconstruction algorithms on the same CTscan and uses repeated measures anova

Comment: While this study:https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00234-020-02574-x  ;which is most similar to ours uses a simple one-way ANOVA or Kruskal-Wallis

Comment: Regarding repeated measures, yes I am "repeating" the measures for each subject, however, I am only measuring the SNR once for each reconstruction algorithm (for each image set).

Comment: I do not think that we can disregard that it is the same patient scan that we are reconstructing in 4 different ways. I think that we must control for the fact that it still is the same patient. What do you think?

Comment: Or, if it makes it easier for you to think. Imagine the following corresponding scenario: You take a blood sample (corresponding to "CT scan") from the patient and measure the glucose level with 4 different apparatus (corresponding to the 4 different image reconstruction algorithms). And then you compare the blood glucose ("the SNR") between the four different apparatus.

Comment: Hello again Robert, I would really appreciate your help with this one if you have time. Thank you in advance! /All the best Michael

Comment: I still think some more details can be helpful. How many patients? How do you measure SNR? ... And pleas, add all new info incomments (both here and on the Q) to the Q as an edit. Not everybody reads comments!